# Not able to fill the whole height of DrawerContentScrollView

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-drawer

I am developing the nagivation drawer:

```
<Drawer.Navigator
    initialRouteName={InitialScreen}
    drawerContent={props => <MyDrawer {...props} />}
    screenOptions={{
        headerShown: true,
    }}>
    <Drawer.Screen name="main" component={MainScreen} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

As you can see above, I am customizing the content of the drawer by implementing my own `MyDrawer` component.

In the rendering part of `MyDrawer`, I have:

```
return (
    <View style={styles.myContent}>
      <DrawerContentScrollView
        style={{flex: 1, top: 0, bottom: 0, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}
        {...props}>
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            flex: 1,
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
          }}>
          <View>
            <DrawerItem name="Purhcase" text="Purchase" />
            <DrawerItem name="Sell" text="Sell" />
          </View>
          ...
        </View>
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
    </View>
  );

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  myContent: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 0,
    paddingTop: 10,
  }
});
```

I would like to have that green color `View` component which wrapped directly by `DrawerContentScrollView` filling the whole height of the `DrawerContentScrollView`. The above code shows what I tried, but no matter what I do, that green color View component always only occupy the height according to what content that it wraps. How to make it fill the whole height then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the `style` prop on your `DrawerContentScrollView` to `contentContainerStyle`.

Comment: Would using that cause drawer items invisible on small screen phones? I mean if it is not scrollable.

Comment: I don't know why it would.

Comment: Aha, sorry, I read wrongly, you meant the style prop, could you please provide a code sample for that style? I haven't used that before.

Comment: <DrawerContentScrollView {...props} contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>

Comment: Cool! Works. I will accept your answer in 4min. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I've fought this particular battle more than once.